# f.readline() doesn't capture the last line of the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I am reading from a very large text file using readline(). The file is several million lines in length. However, whatever I do doesn't capture the last line of the file.

The file I am reading looks like this:

```
$ tail file.txt
22  rs1193135566    0   50807787    C   G   0   0   0   0   NA  0   0   0   NA  NA  0
22  rs1349597430    0   50807793    T   G   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NA  NA  NA  NA
22  rs1230501076    0   50807799    T   G   0   0   NA  NA  0   0   0   NA  0   NA  0
22  22_50807803 0   50807803    C   G   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NA  0
22  rs1488400844    0   50807810    G   T   0   0   0   NA  0   0   0   0   0   NA  0
22  rs1279244475    0   50807811    G   T   0   0   0   NA  0   0   0   0   0   NA  0
22  rs1346432135    0   50807812    G   A   0   NA  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NA  0
22  rs1340490361    0   50807813    C   G   0   0   0   NA  0   0   0   0   0   NA  0
22  22_50807816 0   50807816    G   T   0   0   0   NA  0   0   0   0   0   NA  0
22  rs1412997563    0   50807818    G   C   0   0   0   NA  0   0   0   0   0   NA  0
```

And my code looks like this:

```
with open('/path/file.txt', 'r') as f:

  for l in f:
      line = l.rstrip('\n').split("\t")
      print(line)
```

The last line of the file comes out empty `[]`.

The output looks like this:

```
['22', 'rs1250150067', '0', '50807769', 'G', 'A', 'NA', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0']
['22', 'rs1193135566', '0', '50807787', 'C', 'G', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', 'NA', '0']
['22', 'rs1230501076', '0', '50807799', 'T', 'G', '0', '0', 'NA', 'NA', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0', 'NA', '0']
['22', 'rs1488400844', '0', '50807810', 'G', 'T', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0']
['22', 'rs1346432135', '0', '50807812', 'G', 'A', '0', 'NA', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0']
['22', '22_50807816', '0', '50807816', 'G', 'T', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NA', '0']
['']
```

Comment: `.readline()` is a method of the file, not `str`. Also, you should show the contents of the file. Most likely the last line is just an empty line (e.g. `\n\n`).

Comment: This code only reads the *first* line of the file.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I have included an example of the input, and the last line isn't empty.

Comment: @jasonharper I have edited the code snippet to reflect the loop I am using to read the entirety of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading only one line, try using f.readlines() instead, which will read all the lines. If you wish to use line by line then use subscripting.

```
lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[0]) # to display 1st line
print(lines[1]) # to display 2nd line
```

And so on. You can also print lines in loop, after reading, like

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Edit 1:
It appears in the output you have provided like your loop is not reading all lines, since only second, fourth, sixth lines from end are visible in output.

Also try using strip() instead of rstrip('\n') since this will strip any white space around your string on both sides.

Comment: This wastefully reads the entire ginormous file into memory before doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    with open('/path/file.txt', 'r') as f:
        for lines in f.readlines():
            line = lines.rstrip('\n').split("\t")
            print(line)
```

Comment: I would do that if the file was small, but my file is over 70 million lines long.

Answer (score 0):

You are discarding every other line.

`for line in f` already reads a line into `line`. You then discard that and fetch another line with `line = f.readline()`. My Python 3.5.1 actually warns and aborts:

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

You can read all the lines into memory at once, or process one at a time. I generally recommend the latter unless your processing needs to have all the data in memory in the end (and even then you probably need to parse it into a sane structure, so keeping the raw data in memory is just wasteful).

```
with open('/path/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip('\n').split('\t'))   # or process line
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, but didn't solve the issue yet. At least it doesn't through an error.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an empty line at the end? (Hint: `tail -n 3 file.txt | xxd` or whatever hex dump utility you have available.) Does the last line have a newline? Your symptom would be consistent with doing `f.read().split('\n')` but you don't seem to be doing that.